# Flutter TextFormFiled inside the Card with elevation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have taken a TextFormField in a Card Widget.I am not able to show the error message outside the Card Widget.The error message is showing inside the Card Widget which is not looking good .I have attached the image of the View which I wanted to show.Please Help me out regarding this.
[image: How can achieve this in flutter?]

This is what I get
[image: This is what I get]

Comment: You can't show error message outside the field as you mention the other way around is check for a different condition in the textField and store those result in the string and then use another Text widget to show error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not provided the code I'm going to assume that the card and button have been placed in a Column widget. Also, if you press the button it checks if phone number is present or not, if not present it adds the error message to the card.

If my assumptions are correct, you can use the following instead for the Error message,

`Visibility (
        visible: errmsgvisibility,
        child: Text('Please enter phone number.'),
),`

Where, 'errmsgvisibility' is a bool value which can be simply changed to true to display the message and made to false to hide the message. Make sure you initialize it to false.

Place the code in the Column widget between the Card and the sign in button.